# In Ionic 3 : not able to use font from cahe folder

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

Want to use fonts from application's cache folder.
planned steps:

1. Download font file from my server to application cache folder.
   Sample code

```
    let fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();  
    alert(this.file.cacheDirectory);
    console.log(this.file.cacheDirectory);
    await fileTransfer.download("http://myWebsite.com//HelloButterfly.ttf", this.file.cacheDirectory + '/abcd.ttf');
```

2. Use this font file in css file.
   '''
   CSS code

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'toolbarFont';
        src: url('file:///data/user/0/com.myapppackage/cache/abcd.ttf');
    }
```

html code

```
<p style="font-family: toolbarFont;">some text</p>
```

Step 1 is working fine. but step 2 is not working

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace/FontFace

Comment: Check this link, i think hardcoding the font file is the problem, do it in full dynamic way and it should work.